# Angular: get notified when jwt expired / isAuthenticated should change to false

Tags: angular, jwt, observable

i have got an Angular Application with JWT Authentication.

I check the status in the token-auth.service.ts

```
public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');

    if (token) {
      if(this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)){
       
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }else{
      
      //this.destroyToken();
      return false;
    }

  }
```

To get notified when the status changes, i added this to the service

```
private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.isAuthenticated());

   get LoggedInChanged(){
    return this.isAuthenticated().asObservable();
  }
```

in the app.component.ts is subscribe to observable:

```
  ngOnInit() {

    
    this.tokenAuthService.LoggedInChanged.subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res)
      if (res) {
        console.log('eingeloggt '+ res)  ;
        
        
      } else {
        console.log('ausgeloggt '+ res);
      }
    });
```

But when the JWT expires, i dont get a log on the console.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think this has nothing to do with the JWT, you are setting a current value in behaviour subject but he doesn't know that the function return another value, it just setted up a value, you will need to check the function all the time and detect it this way... Can you try and change this isAuthenticated() function:

```js
public isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
   const token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
   return of(!!token && !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token) ? true : false);
}
```

And after that you will need only:

```js
public loggedInChanged: Observable<boolean> = this.isAuthenticated();
```

Now when you subscribe to loggedInChange I think you will detect the changes.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and it totally makes sense. 
I changed as you told and my ngOnInit in app.component.ts looks like this
`ngOnInit() {

    this.tokenAuthService.loggedInChanged.subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res)
      this.isLoggedin = res;
      console.log('login changed')
    });

    
    } 
   
  }`
bus there is again no console message